# Excel Pivot Table issue setting a column to "Running Total" using VBA

Tags: excel, for-loop, pivot-table, vba

I am using VBA to loop through pivot tables in order to update the values to include new data (from external source) and to update the start and end dates for the groupings. This code works...

```
For Each pvt In ws.PivotTables

    For Each pvtFld In pvt.RowFields
        rowLabel = pvtFld.Name
        pvtFld.DataRange.Group Start:=startDate, End:=endDate, By:=7, Periods:=Array(False, False, False, True, False, False, False)
    Next pvtFld ...

[Trouble code will go here, but let me explain further]

Next pvt
```

The problem that I am encountering is that upon refresh all of the "running totals" are reset to "no calculation.

Recording a macro is helpful but not useful for other spreadsheets

```
' Sets the "Total" Column from each Pivot to "Running Total"
With ws.PivotTables("LOEPivot").PivotFields( _
    "Total Planned LOE")
    .Calculation = xlRunningTotal
    .BaseField = "MOI"
End With
```

So, I tried to embed another `For each` like this...

```
For each pvtCol in pvt.ColumnFields
    if pvtCol.Name Like .Name & "Total" Then
       pvtCol.Calculation = xlRunningTotal
    end if 
Next pvtCol
```

This doesn't work though b/c the Column Names equal the string "Values"

Is there a different method or property that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same difficulty, however I found the solution. After looking what my marco did i found out that it set the 'base field' wrong (right click on the pivot > show values as > running totals in > [shows base field]).

By adding `.BaseField` (e.g. .BaseField = "Week number") after `.calculation` you should be able to solve this issue.

Potentially this link will also help you http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/Excel_VBA/Running_Total.html.